# Can I drink more than one potion in one round?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, actions, alchemist, potions

One of the players I play with said that it is not allowed by the rules that you drink more than one potion in one round, but he could not find the rule anymore.

Let us say I have the [Potion Glutton Feat](https://sites.google.com/site/pathfinderogc/feats/general-feats/potion-glutton?overridemobile=true) (swift action) and want to drink a [Mutagen](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist#TOC-Mutagen-Su-) (standard action) would I be allowed to drink more than one potion in one round?

Comment: What does the player say happens when a creature that's technically capable of consuming a second potion tries to consume that second potion?  Does the creature, like, spill it? Does the creature succeed yet the second potion has no effect and is wasted? *Does the universe explode?*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no such rule that I can find, and I tend to think that I would have heard of it if it existed. It certainly isn’t to be found anywhere in the potion rules, which is where such a rule *should* be found.

And even if the rule existed, a mutagen is not technically a potion in any event, and wouldn’t interfere with that rule. The only way you could possibly be prevented from doing this is if the mutagen class feature said you could not drink a mutagen the same round you drink a potion. The mutagen class feature does not say any such thing, nor has any errata or FAQ for mutagens (that I have seen) said this.

Normally you could not do so just because of action limits, but Potion Glutton is one way around that. Note, however, that Potion Glutton *only* gets around the action limitation if you have at least one potion in hand—if you have to pull both potions out, you won’t be able to drink the second one (move to draw one, swift to drink it, standard→move to draw the other, out of actions). Unfortunately, the nerfed Pathfinder version of Quick Draw doesn’t help here, either.

Comment: Is it worth mentioning that other folks can pour potions down a helpless creature's gullet and that multiple creature during a lone round could do so? (Obviously, this doesn't change the time it takes to consume a mutagen, but it does lend credence to multiple potions being able to affect the same creature during the same round.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan Unless there’s something explicitly saying multiple creatures can do that, I think it just would be another “way around that [action limitation].”

Comment: I'd certainly allow that, but definitely *not* during combat.

Comment: @Obie2.0 Why not? Puts me in mind of a boxer who goes to the corner, and has people rubbing sweat off him, squeezing water in his mouth, giving him tips. It’s longer than a combat round, but meh, this is fantasy. And the rules certainly allow it.

Comment: @KRyan from how I read the potion glutton feat, I would say that during combat they could drink one potion without consequence but the potion taken as a normal action would provoke the opportunity attack as normal. So yes they could drink two potions in one round technically but one would have the normal penalty applied to it while the other didn't basically. (Also basing this off having seen "swift action" and "bonus action" used somewhat interchangeably in the PH.)

Comment: @Varis I have never seen “bonus action” used in Pathfinder; I don’t think it ever is. But yes, the potion drunk normally, without using Potion Glutton, would provoke an attack of opportunity. Never suggested otherwise? Provoking isn’t always that big a deal.

Comment: @KRyan Sorry didn't see the pathfinder tag, but my assumption is kinda based on bonus actions being described as "especially swift" so was assuming it was similar in that sense. And I just thought that the opportunity attack was worth mentioning, but as you say it's not always that big of a deal.

Comment: Precisely, it's longer than a combat round. If carefully arranged ahead of time in a safe situation it would be one thing. I just don't see multiple people being able to pour potions into someone's mouth simultaneously while they're all trying to avoid being killed by monsters or whatever.

Comment: @Obie2.0 And a 1st-level human barbarian can outrun world-record sprint speeds, and do it for minutes at a time while wielding a battleaxe, wearing chain, and carrying 50-odd pounds of other gear. IMO, you should be very careful about restricting PCs based on reality; PCs in this game are not limited the way real-life humans are. See also [Guy at the Gym Fallacy](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?303089-The-Guy-at-the-Gym-Fallacy).

Comment: @KRyan - I'd be perfectly fine with allowing some kind of "collaborative potion-pouring" feat. But while PCs get to have magic combat powers even if they're not spellcasters, they shouldn't get to have them for *free*. A "collaborative potion-pouring" feat? A DC 30 Dexterity check on the part of each pourer? Sure. But letting them do a superhuman action for free, no.

Comment: @Obie2.0 I'm not sure what you're imagining is problem here, but [the rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/potions/) say, "A character can carefully administer a potion to an unconscious creature as a full-round action, trickling the liquid down the creature’s throat. Likewise, it takes a full-round action to apply an oil to an unconscious creature." It's not like in the middle of combat one ally can dump a potion down another ally's gullet. Just sayin'. (I only brought up the idea because the question's unclear on what may happen if a second potion *is* administered in the same round.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan - I don’t think there’s a problem.

Comment: @Obie2.0 RE: "I just don't see multiple people being able to pour potions into someone's mouth simultaneously while they're all trying to avoid being killed by monsters or whatever." That sounded like you'd some concerns that this tactic could be abused; I wanted to assuage those concerns. My apologies if I misunderstood.